# How do I implement masked Softmax?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Consider:

```
input = {1, 2, 3};
mask = {1, 0, 1}
```

Classic Softmax:

```
SoftmaxLayer[]@input
```

> {0.0900306, 0.244728, 0.665241}

Masked Softmax is something like this:

```
SoftmaxLayer[]@Pick[input, mask, 1]
```

> {0.119203, 0.880797}

But zeros must be preserved:

> {0.119203, 0., 0.880797}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
MaskedSoftmax = NetGraph[
  {
   ElementwiseLayer[Exp],
   ThreadingLayer[Times],
   {SummationLayer[], ElementwiseLayer[Max[#, 10^-15] &], ReplicateLayer[Automatic]},
   ThreadingLayer[Divide]
   },
  {
   NetPort["Input"] -> 1 -> 2,
   NetPort["Mask"] -> 2,
   2 -> 3,
   {2, 3} -> 4
   }
  ]
```

[image]

```
MaskedSoftmax[<|"Input" -> {1, 2, 3}, "Mask" -> {1, 0, 1}|>]
```

> {0.119203, 0., 0.880797}

```
MaskedSoftmax[<|"Input" -> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}, "Mask" -> {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}|>]
```

> {{0.119203, 0., 0.880797}, {0., 1., 0.}}

```
MaskedSoftmax[<|"Input" -> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}, "Mask" -> {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}|>]
```

> {{0.119203, 0., 0.880797}, {0., 0., 0.}}